# Automapper - CreateMap called multiple times

Tags: automapper

What happens when I call Mapper.CreateMap with the same types multiple times?

Does it rewrite the previous map? If so, is it possible to make it throw an exception if I try to create map, that is already created?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When calling Mapper.CreateMap for the same set of source and destination several times, nothing will happen at all as the `Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>()` does not set up any extensions for a mapping configuration.
If you set the overrides for IMappingExpression like this 
`Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>().ConstructUsing(x=>new TDestination(x.SomeField))`,
than yes, the configuration for this mapping will be replaced with the new one.
Regarding the second part of your question, I know the way to verify if the map was already created:

```
public TDestination Resolve<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)
{
     var mapped = Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDestination)); //this will give you a reference to existing mapping if it was created or NULL if not

     if (mapped == null)
     {
        var expression = Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDestination>();
     }
     return Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(source);
}
```

Comment: Little late, but I believe it answers the question.

Comment: is there any overhead calling it again and again? let's say if its in the constructor of a class?

Comment: Very late response, but for the benefit of anyone else reading, YES! I'm currently staring at a performance report where 60% CPU time is spent calling Mapper.CreateMap (with extensions like the above answer)

Comment: @Talonj - There is expected to be a high overhead for calling CreateMap, but if `FindTypeMapFor(...)` is returning an existing map then `CreateMap` should not be called repeatedly.